# jmeter - IllegalAccessError

Tags: jmeter

I have installed Java and Jmeter successfully however I am not able to save my test plans on my machine. Please advise?[image]

```
Uncaught Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.fulechooser.DarkFilePanelUIBridge$DetailsTableModel <in unnamed module @0x21507a04> cannot access class sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder <in module java.desktop> because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt.shell to unnamed module @0y21507a04 in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] See log for details.
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you running your Jmeter in the Dark mode/Dark theme? If so, try changing the theme and see if that works.
Some people faced this issue and changing the theme resolved it.

In Jmeter go to `Options > Look and Feel` and try different theme. Then restart Jmeter.

Another thing is to check the version of Java. Jmeter is best compatible with Java 8. So you can also try changing the version of Java on your system.

If that also doesn't work, you can try the other solutions mentioned by Dmitri T regarding the nightly build or changing line 112 of jmeter.bat script.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're suffering from [JMeter Bug 65300](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65300), the workarounds are in:

1. Install [nightly build of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)
2. Downgrade to [Java 8](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3), it's the minimum sufficient version to launch [JMeter 5.4](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter5-4-new-features-and-abilities)
3. If you cannot downgrade Java for any reason and cannot use the nightly builds you can change [line 112 of jmeter.bat script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat#L112) to look like

   ```
   set JAVA9_OPTS=--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
   ```